# Bug in CLR? CLR execution engine failed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, clr

AFAIK, `try` and `finally` block are used execute a piece of code that might throw some `exception`, we also add `catch` block if we are prepared to handle some type of exception and/or are excepting them, like `FileIOException`, `AccessRight` or something. But when I ran this..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Environment.FailFast("It failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
```

Its breaks with an exception and says

**FatalExecutionEngineError was detected

Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x032526f4, on thread 0xd04. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.**

Now [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> Usually, when an unhandled exception ends an application, whether or
>   not the finally block is run is not important. However, if you have
>   statements in a finally block that must be run even in that situation,
>   one solution is to add a catch block to the try-finally statement.

So, I added the `catch` block, but still it says the same thing.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Environment.FailFast("It failed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
```

It failed again with the same error. As for CLR saying the code block in finally always runs (at least when catch is added), it surely is not the case. Reviews/Opinions anyone?

Also here's the snapshot..

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. The purpose of `Environment.FailFast` is to halt execution immediately. By design it will not run any code in catch or finally blocks.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx) says:

> This method terminates a process without running any active
>   try/finally blocks or finalizers.
>
> The FailFast method writes the message string to the Windows
>   Application event log, creates a dump of your application, and then
>   terminates the current process. The messa string is also included in
>   error reporting to Microsoft.
>
> Use the FailFast method instead of the Exit method to terminate your
>   application if the state of your application is damaged beyond repair,
>   and executing your application's try/finally blocks and finalizers
>   will corrupt program resources.

This makes it clear that code in your finally blocks will not run. If there was a way to make code run after `Environment.FailFast` then that would render `Environment.FailFast` pretty much useless. Its very existence is predicated on the fact that your code does not execute after you call it.

You point to documentation that states (emphasis mine):

> Usually, when an **unhandled exception ends an application**, whether or not the finally block is run is not important. However, if you have statements in a finally block that must be run even in that situation, one solution is to add a catch block to the try-finally statement.

But those words simply do not apply here. You are assuming that when you call `Environment.FailFast`, an unhandled exception terminates the application. That is not the case. The application is just terminated on the spot – there is no unhandled exception.